# Is there a way to integrate sonarlint plugin in pom.xml

Tags: java, plugins, maven-3, sonarlint

I want to add sonarlint plugin to my project. When I build with maven, the plugin should be automatically enabled without my intervention. Is there a way I could do it?

Comment: What do you mean enabled? SonarLint is used in the IDE and must be installed in each IDE.

Comment: I mean plugin should be automatically installed into ide. when maven is building the project,by putting something in  pluginmanagement tag of pom.xml

Comment: Can you suggest me some way, i could do it by adding some jars or anything that could help, basically i dont want to install it from eclipse marketeclipse

Comment: SonarLint is not a maven plugin; You need to install the plugin in Eclipse or IntelliJ. In both IDEs, you can install it from a local file, if that makes any difference. If you want to trigger an analysis with maven and send the results to your instance of SonarQube, you can use the maven sonar plugin.

Comment: What i want to do is ,  perform continuous integration with sonar lint

Comment: Most likely you would have to find some way to call sonar-java-plugin which is the heart of sonarlint's static analyzer.

Answer (score 4):

SonarLint is a local plugin that can be embedded in your IDE.
In the plugin setting you can put the "Automatically trigger analysis" in order to have feedback while writing. 
In order to perform continuous integration you should use SonarQube, it is possible to integrate it with [Jenkins](https://docs.sonarqube.org/latest/analysis/jenkins/) or [Codemagic](https://docs.sonarqube.org/latest/analysis/codemagic/) and also with [Maven](https://docs.sonarqube.org/latest/analysis/scan/sonarscanner-for-maven/).
It is possible to add SonarQube to your pull requests as well. 
You can see the doc [here](https://docs.sonarqube.org/latest/analysis/pull-request/)

You can find more information about the difference between SonarLint and SonarQube [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39828609/sonarqube-and-sonarlint-difference)