# SonarLint vs SonarTS

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, sonarqube, sonarlint

I am really confused about [SonarLint](https://www.sonarlint.org/) and [SonarTS](https://www.sonarsource.com/products/codeanalyzers/sonarts.html).

I have used [SonarLint](https://www.sonarlint.org/) in my Visual Studio, but my client ask me to use [SonarTs plugin](https://github.com/Pablissimo/SonarTsPlugin/releases/tag/v1.0.0)

> [SonarLint](https://www.sonarlint.org/) does analysis for overall project and [SonarTS](https://www.sonarsource.com/products/codeanalyzers/sonarts.html) does analysis for only Typescript Projects. **Am I correct?** Does [SonarTsPlugine](https://github.com/Pablissimo/SonarTsPlugin/releases/tag/v1.0.0) support C# code? I am totally confused. I have an idea about [SonarQube And SonarLint difference](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39828609/sonarqube-and-sonarlint-difference), but no idea about [SonarLint](https://www.sonarlint.org/) and [SonarTS](https://www.sonarsource.com/products/codeanalyzers/sonarts.html).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

SonarLint is an IDE extension for IntelliJ IDEA, Eclipse, Visual Studio, VS Code, Atom.

SonarLint includes a list of language analyzer plugins, and SonarTS is the one for Typescript.

To check if SonarLint support TypeScript in your IDE visit https://www.sonarlint.org/ and click on your IDE name.

At the time I'm wiring this answer, TypeScript is included in SonarLint for VS Code, but not in SonarLint for Visual Studio.

Comment: I ran `SonarLint`. it Supports typescript as well other projects.  Could you please take a look at this question? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48580783/unmet-peer-dependency-angular-compiler2-4-5

Answer (score 0):

[SonarTs Plugin](https://github.com/Pablissimo/SonarTsPlugin) is a community plugin for SonarQube to analyse TypeScript code.

1. if you install it on your SonarQube
2. if you use connected mode of SonarLint in your IDE

then probably you can profit from [SonarTs Plugin](https://github.com/Pablissimo/SonarTsPlugin) in your IDE (while I'm not sure if TS files will be at all analysed)