# UNMET PEER DEPENDENCY @angular/compiler@2.4.5

Tags: node.js, typescript, npm, sonarqube, tslint

I am getting that error while doing `npm install tslint-sonarts`

I know the error says I need  Compiler version for `2.4.5`  I am using `"@angular/compiler": "^2.1.0"`. I don't want upgrade the version because of i need to change all other dependency version.

So i need the correct compatible version of sonarts  for `"@angular": "^2.1.0",`

I have checked the [release log](https://github.com/SonarSource/SonarTS/releases) for that package. I have also tried very old version (SonarTS 1.2.0) of that package. But it still throwing that error. Is any lower than `SonarTS 1.2.0` version is available for it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`tslint-sonarts` does not require a `@angular/compiler`. And it never did. It must be another package which requires `@angular/compiler`.