# What is the difference between Lint option available in Android Studio and SonarQube?

Tags: android, static-code-analysis

In Android Studio there is an option to do static code analysis using Lint(Analyze --> Inspect code...). Wanted to know the difference between the code analysis using the Lint and SonarQube.

Comment: There is already an answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39828609/sonarqube-and-sonarlint-difference#:~:text=SonarQube%20is%20a%20server%20where,be%20executed%20via%20CLI%20commands.). Hope this is what you are looking for.

Comment: @akhil thanks for your reply. Do you mean that SonarLint and Lint available with Android Studio both are same?

Comment: Yes they are same if am not wrong.

Comment: @akhilnair Not the same at all. There are many linters that do slightly different things and catch different issues. Android's built-in is there by default, `lint` and `lintAnalyze`, then there's `lintKotlin` from Kotlinter, and `sonar` to run Sonar's analysis. They are unique analyses that will catch different things. You may want to run all three. There will be some overlap.