# is it possible to install SonarQube on PyCharm?

Tags: pycharm, sonarqube

From [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/39836205/19927107) answer, I understand that SonarLint lives in the IDE. And I have installed it as well in my PyCharm, but I have been asked to install SonarQube on PyCharm. On the python interpreter (in PyCharm), I'm seeing packages like, sonarqube-py, sonarqube_api, python-sonarqube-api, opn-sonarqibe-api. I wonder what are these? I wanted to ask if it's possible to install SQ on PyCharm. I have tried google search but I think there are not many results. If it's not possible then what will I have to do to run SonarQube?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

SonarQube is a separate application, and SonarLint is a plugin for IDE that needs to connect to SonarQube.
So I don't think installing SonarQube in your IDE makes sense.
But in your SonarLint configuration in PyCharm you'll need to provide the SonarQube URL.

Comment: when i write a program in PyCharm, i right click, and i get an option: 'Analyze with SonarLint' and it seems to point errors/suggestions for my code. can u pls explain where do we need to provide the SonarQube URL (and why)?

Comment: I guess there might be default embedded coding rules in the plugin. But I think you'll only get default behaviors and will be limited in terms of customization.
But if you plan to scan your project in a CI/CD process, you'll need anyway a SonarQube instance :)